# Password mismatch while logging to sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Alright, I have a classic asp application and I have a connection string to try to connect to db.

MY connection string looks as follows:

```
 Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MYPC\MSSQLSERVER;Initial
 Catalog=mydb;database=mydb;User Id=me;Password=123
```

Now when I'm accessing db though front-en I get this error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e4d'
Login failed for user 'me'.
```

I looked in the sql profiler and I got this:

```
 Login failed for user 'me'.  Reason: Password did not match that
 for the login provided. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
 Error: 18456, State:8.
```

What I've tried:

*checked 100 times that my password is actually correct.
*Tried this: `alter login me with check_policy off` (Do not even know why I did this)
*Enable ALL possible permissions for this account in SSMS.
* I've tried this connection string: `Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MYPC\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=mydb;database=mydb; Integrated Security = SSPI`

And I got this error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005' Cannot open database mydb requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Answer (score 3):

The only times I have ever seen the State 8 error for 18456 (Password Mismatch) was in fact a password mismatch. Try a new password. Type it in notepad, copy and paste it to SQL and then do the same into your app config. Make sure nothing is happening to that password when it is being handed off to SQL - no trimming, extra spaces, etc.

But then the second error you got seems to indicate you may have gotten past that bad password error and are now unable to access your database.

That can be one of a few things:

1.) Verify the database specified really does exist.
2.) Verify that the login you are using has been granted appropriate permissions into that database (If the permissions are at the SQL Server system administrator level then this shouldn't be a necessary step)

That's where I'd start anyway.

Comment: I already did everything mentioned above. no success :(

Comment: So you can log in fine with SQL Server Management Studio with that user and password?

Comment: yes. I actually can do that in ssms.

Comment: and no errors whatsoever? That's a really interesting one because normally those two error state are more or less clear cut. have you tried to change the password to something really simple?

Comment: So, now I figured that the exact connection string does work in .net app. Still does not work in asp though. I believe, since the profiler says login failed, I assume, this has something to do with some kind of encryption. But I do not know how to monitor what exactly was passed to sql server. Do you know how can I check what exactly goes into sql server?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of how you could see that from the SQL Server perspective. You could try a few things.. You could output the final connection string to a text box or file. You could try not encrypting and see if it works to at least rule that in. You could potentially see the connection string being passed using a network monitoring tool like wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) or netmon (https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865).

Comment: You can't use wireshark to monitor the authentication part of the process.  Authentication is encrypted using SSL via a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you specifying "Initial Catalog=mydb;database=mydb;"?  You should be using one or the other, not both.

Your connection string should look like this.

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MYPC\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=mydb;User Id=me;Password=123
```

Comment: Just tried. The same error

Comment: Is the instance case sensitive?  Try removing the Initial Catalog section and see if you can connect to the database instance.  You'll probably get missing object errors unless the login is setup with the correct default database on the instance, but we need to make sure you can just connect correctly at this point.